# Mann-Whitney-U test

Tags: r, apply, p-value

I have a csv with several thousands of samples whose gene expression after different treatments should be compared:

```
ID    U1         U2        U3        H1        H2        H3
1     5.95918   6.07211   6.01437   5.89113   5.89776   5.95443
2     6.56789   5.98897   6.67844   5.78987   6.01789   6.12789
..
```

I was asked to do a [Mann Whitney u test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test) and R is giving me results when I use this:

```
results <- apply(data,1,function(x){wilcox.test(x[1:3],x[4:6])$pvalue})
```

However, I just get values like 0.1 or 0.5..

When I added `alternative ="greater"` I got values like 0.35000 or 0.05000 and a few samples got pvalues like 0.14314 (that's a value I am okay with).
So I am wondering why R is giving me such strange pvalues (0.35000,..) and how I can fix it to get "normal" pvalues.

Comment: We need some sample data, ... and you should fix your shift key. Failing to capitalize decreases human readability. You should also show what you mean by "playing around". (It makes very little sense to compare 3 items to 3 items with M-W. Describing the experimental setup may allow better responses from a statistical perspective.)

Comment: I hope thats okay now..why can't i compare 3 values with 3 values?  sorry, I never used this test before..

Comment: Your non-parametric test is effectively looking at how 'shuffled' your data is - and with only 3+3 samples, there aren't many possible shuffles, so the p-values will be very discrete.  Unfortunately three replicates is common in genomics - you should look at the `limma` package within bioconductor if you've got lots of genes (rows) so you can share variability information across genes.

Comment: You can compare them but whether the outcome of that comparison makes *any* statistical sense is another thing entirely. Non-parametric tests tend to have lower power than their parametric equivalents (as you throw away a lot of the data and just retain the rank order), so with 3 observations per groups I doubt you have anywhere near enough information to detect all but huge differences.

Comment: Also, you need to be aware of the issue of multiple comparisons; if you are doing several thousand "tests" assuming and error rate of 0.05, you'd expect to find on average 50 significant differences simply due to random chance per every 1000 "tests". There are better approaches to testing for differences in gene expression per group.

Comment: thanks Gavin! I thought about using p.adjust to adjust the p-values with the Benjamini Hochberg procedure (fdr). And I am going to look into that limma package right now.

Comment: @GavinSimpson "all but huge differences": `wilcox.test(-1e9+1:3,1e9+1:3)` still has a p-value of 0.1 (as pointed out by Roland below)

Comment: @BenBolker That'll learn me to fire something off without checking. Thanks for the fact check :-)

Comment: One approach that might make a little more sense, would be to take the average expression for each gene across replicates, then you can compare your Untreated vs. Treated groups (which should have thousands of samples each).

Answer (score 5):

You are doing a non-parametric test, where the test statistics is derived from the ranks. With a sample size of 3, there are just a few possible distinct values for the test statistics.

Example:

```
set.seed(42)
x <- matrix(rnorm(3000), ncol=6)
ps <- apply(x, 1, function(a) wilcox.test(a[1:3], a[4:6])$p.value)
table(ps)
#ps
#0.1 0.2 0.4 0.7   1 
# 54  45 108 141 152
```

Comment: oh..so I should not use this test as I have to few replicates? I thought I would get values that are kind of similar to a ttest, basically allowing me to say that the expression is different between the two treatments.

Comment: You should consult a statistician. I would be very wary of your approach due to alpha error inflation. And a sample size of 3 poses serious problems with statistical power for parametric tests. Using a non-parametric test with such small sample sizes is a joke.

Comment: well, sorry unfortunately I only got that data and cannot do anything about the sample sizes. Thanks four your time anyway